# Reusing generator expressions

Tags: python, generator, generator-expression

Generator expressions is an extremely useful tool, and has a huge advantage over list comprehensions, which is the fact that it does not allocate memory for a new array.

The problem I am facing with generator expressions, which eventually makes me end up writing list comprehensions, is that I can only use a such a generator once:

```
>>> names = ['John', 'George', 'Paul', 'Ringo']
>>> has_o = (name for name in names if 'o' in name)
>>> for name in has_o:
...   print(name.upper())
...
JOHN
GEORGE
RINGO
>>> for name in has_o:
...   print(name.lower())
...
>>>
```

The above code illustrates how the generator expression can only be used once. That's of course, because the generator expression returns **an instance** of the generator, rather than defining a generator function which could be instantiated again and again.

Is there a way to clone the generator each time it is used, in order to make it reusable, or to make the generator expressions syntax return a generator function rather than a single instance?

Comment: There's `itertools.tee`, but you can't both have your memory-optimised generator *and* have it reusable too. If you need it to be memory efficient you need to re-create the generator, otherwise a list comprehension is probably what you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make it a `lambda`:

```
has_o = lambda names: (name for name in names if 'o' in name)
for name in has_o(["hello","rrrrr"]):
   print(name.upper())
for name in has_o(["hello","rrrrr"]):
   print(name.upper())
```

`lambda` is a one-liner and *returns* a new generator each time. Here I chose to be able to pass the input list, but if it's fixed, you don't even need a parameter:

```
names = ["hello","rrrrr"]
has_o = lambda: (name for name in names if 'o' in name)
for name in has_o():
   print(name.upper())
for name in has_o():
   print(name.upper())
```

In that last case, be careful about the fact that if `names` changes or is reassigned, the `lambda` uses the new `names` object. You can fix the name reassigning by using the default value trick:

```
has_o = lambda lst=names: (name for name in lst if 'o' in name)
```

and you can fix the afterwards modification of `names` by using the default value-and-copy trick (not super-useful when you think your first goal was to avoid a list to be created :)):

```
has_o = lambda lst=names[:]: (name for name in lst if 'o' in name)
```

(now make your pick :))

Comment: I really like the second code example, this is really robust and enables you to "forget" how the generator has been created

Comment: thanks. You cannot completely forget, since it still relies on `names`. But using a default value for the lambda should fix that. edited to show the potential problems and how to fix them if needed

Comment: I agree, but the fact it relies on `names` will be true even if you use the generator expression as is, wouldn't it? Is it going each time instantiated to use the `names` array it has in its scope, rather than the original `names` it had been created with?

Comment: yes, sometimes you _want_ to follow `names`. It depends on what you want to achieve. I'm giving the different solutions.

Comment: Thank you, it is a great answer. I would change the order and put the last two examples first, since I **think** this is the most common functionality people want, and that way they will be able to just pick your solution immediately

Comment: @AgvaniaRekuva thanks. I just wanted to show the various methods, from the simplest, to the most complex. Also note that creating a list comprehension is very fast, iterating on a generator comprehension is slower, so if you really want the lazy evaluation thingy/memory saving, ok (or if `names` change and you want to reflect that) but most of the time, listcomps are better.

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) allows you to make several iterators out of one iterable:

```
from itertools import tee

names = ['John', 'George', 'Paul', 'Ringo']
has_o_1, has_o_2 = tee((name for name in names if 'o' in name), 2)
print('iterable 1')
for name in has_o_1:
    print(name.upper())
print('iterable 2')
for name in has_o_2:
    print(name.upper())
```

Output:

```
iterable 1
JOHN
GEORGE
RINGO
iterable 2
JOHN
GEORGE
RINGO
```

Comment: Warning: `tee` is really only suitable for cases where all resulting iterators will be advanced in mostly tandem (e.g. to make a windowing iterator, you might `tee` the original, advance each resulting iterator by a differing amount, then iterate over all the iterators `zip`ed together), because it caches all values produced until the last `tee`-ed iterator consumes them. Thus, in this scenario, the entire output of the generator expression gets cached in the first loop, and isn't cleared until the second loop runs. It's slower, and saves nothing on memory, vs. calling `list` on the genexpr.

Answer (score -1):

OK people, here is a code that makes your iterator reusable.
It resets itself automatically after each iteration so you do not have to worry about anything.
How efficient it is, well, it is two method calls (one next() for tee() which in turn calls next() of the iterator itself), and a try-except block extra on top of the original iterator.
You have to decide if a tiny speed loss is OK or use lambda to reconstruct the iterator as shown in other answer.

```
from itertools import tee

class _ReusableIter:
    """
    This class creates a generator object that wraps another generator and makes it reusable
    again after each iteration is finished.
    It makes two "copies" (using tee()) of an original iterator and iterates over the first one.
    The second "copy" is saved for later use.
    After first iteration reaches its end, it makes two "copies" of the saved "copy", and
    the previous iterator is swapped with the new first "copy" which is iterated over while the second "copy" (a "copy" of the old "copy") waits for the
    end of a new iteration, and so on.
    After each iteration, the _ReusableIter() will be ready to be iterated over again.

    If you layer a _ReusableIter() over another _ReusableIter(), the result can lead you into an indefinite loop,
    or provoke some other unpredictable behaviours.
    This is caused by later explained problem with copying instances of _ReusableIter() with tee().
    Use ReusableIterator() factory function to initiate the object.
    It will prevent you from making a new layer over an already _ReusableIter()
    and return that object instead.

    If you use the _ReusableIter() inside nested loops the first loop
    will get the first element, the second the second, and the last nested loop will
    loop over the rest, then as the last loop is done, the iterator will be reset and
    you will enter the infinite loop. So avoid doing that if the mentioned behaviour is not desired.

    It makes no real sense to copy the _ReusableIter() using tee(), but if you think of doing it for some reason, don't.
    tee() will not do a good job and the original iterator will not really be copied.
    What you will get instead is an extra layer over THE SAME _ReusableIter() for every copy returned.

    TODO: A little speed improvement can be achieved here by implementing tee()'s algorithm directly into _ReusableIter()
    and dump the tee() completely.
    """
    def __init__ (self, iterator):
        self.iterator, self.copy = tee(iterator)
        self._next = self.iterator.next

    def reset (self):
        self.iterator, self.copy = tee(self.copy)
        self._next = self.iterator.next

    def next (self):
        try:
            return self._next()
        except StopIteration:
            self.reset()
            raise

    def __iter__ (self):
        return self

def ReusableIter (iterator):
    if isinstance(iterator, _ReusableIter):
        return iterator
    return _ReusableIter(iterator)

Usage:
>>> names = ['John', 'George', 'Paul', 'Ringo']
>>> has_o = ReusableIter(name for name in names if 'o' in name)
>>> for name in has_o:
>>>     print name
John
George
Ringo
>>> # And just use it again:
>>> for name in has_o:
>>>     print name
John
George
Ringo
>>>
```

Comment: Warning: `tee` is really only suitable for cases where all resulting iterators will be advanced in mostly tandem (e.g. to make a windowing iterator, you might `tee` the original, advance each resulting iterator by a differing amount, then iterate over all the iterators `zip`ed together), because it caches all values produced until the last `tee`-ed iterator consumes them. Thus, in this scenario, the entire output of the generator expression gets cached in the first loop, and isn't cleared until the second loop runs. It's slower, and saves nothing on memory, vs. calling `list` on the genexpr.

Comment: This particular design in particular is *guaranteed* to not release any memory once the first iteration it complete, until `has_o` is freed (causing the `tee`-ed iterators it contains to be cleaned up as well), so it would be *much* more efficient, with much less custom code and faster performance, to just replace `has_o = ReusableIter(name for name in names if 'o' in name)` with `has_o = [name for name in names if 'o' in name]`, making a `list` in the first place. The first loop can run before all elements are produced, but it's slower and wastes more memory in all other ways.

Comment: @ShadowRanger : 1. tee() is suitable wherever a developer finds it suitable, there is no "really" about it; 2. Did you see TODO in my __doc__ string, although original tee() is not the best example to follow exactly; 3. Whoever needs to implement real ReusableIter() needs to use eval() or exec on original iterator's code to copy it instead of using tee(), the concept stays the same

Comment: 1) If a `list` is strictly better on speed and memory consumption, it's hard to justify `tee`. You always have 1+ untouched `tee` iterators, so you store *all* the data from the source; you're a `list` with extra steps. Saying "it's suitable if you think it's suitable" is like saying that adding no-op spin loops to the beginning of every function is suitable; it makes everything slower and worse, and it does it in an inefficient way. 2) The TODO is irrelevant, your design (that allows reiterating again forever) can never work on arbitrary iterators. 3) `eval` could work. But this can't.

Comment: @ShadowRanger : I am sorry but it obviously works. At least PVM says so. If you do not find it suitable doesn't mean that nobody does. Thanks for pointing out deficiencies of tee(). Whether creating a list each time or my iterator object is faster should be timed though. Memory wise, also can be tricky as Python's internal optimizations can surprise you at times. As soon as you are done using the iterator you delete it, and memory will be released. What is interesting here is the concept and the idea, and you should think more outside the box and do something to activate your creativity.

Comment: I say these things because I do know the internals (I've made a few small contributions to the CPython core, and written several CPython extensions for my employer), and I have timed stuff like this before. And your own design *prevents* the reclamation of memory for precisely as long as creating it as a `list` would do so. That's the whole point. If it were just using `tee` the once, it could eventually be reclaimed, but you're actually creating *nested* `tee`s that must store multiple references to the same data indefinitely (similar to making multiple shallow copied `list`s).

Comment: It clearly *works*, it's just *pointless*, because `>>> has_o = ReusableIter(name for name in names if 'o' in name)` could be replaced with `>>> has_o = [name for name in names if 'o' in name]` or (if someone else made the genexpr) `>>> has_o = list(name for name in names if 'o' in name)` achieving the same result with none of this waste. Just because it's *a* solution doesn't make it a *good* one, thus my criticism. There are many bad ways to solve a problem, this is just one more of them.

Comment: @ShadowRanger : I never said that something is suitable because I or you think it is suitable, I said that saying that something is "only really suitable" for this or that and similar phrases have no place in programming. BTW, I saw no-op used in similar manner you described and for, believe it or not, micro-optimization purposes, because it caused a compiler to behave in a certain way and produce properly aligned machine code. And I saw even worse paradoxes.

Comment: I never claimed that the solution is a good one. At the time of writing this answer I even didn't know how exactly tee() works under the hood. And documentation had no label saying "tee() is only really suitable for this/that", and no mention of caching was there. When I realised how it is implemented I was honestly astonished. Anyway, are you going about copying code from the internet meant to improve something without actually checking the performance? Because no-one should do that and I hope no-one does.

Comment: The docs for `tee` have said, for a *very* long time (a similar warning exists at least as far back as 2.6, the oldest docs I could find off-hand, and it was only added in 2.4): "This itertool may require significant auxiliary storage (depending on how much temporary data needs to be stored). In general, if one iterator uses most or all of the data before another iterator starts, it is faster to use `list()` instead of `tee()`."