# Reusable unbounded range

Tags: python, iterable

There are [multiple questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186336/unbounded-range) here asking about infinite `range` that all recommend  `itertools.count`. However, `range` has one ability that `count` does not—it can be reused.

```
a = range(100)

# Prints 0 1 2 3
for i in a:
    print(i)
    if i >= 3:
        break

# Prints 0 1 2 3
for i in a:
    print(i)
    if i >= 3:
        break

from itertools import count
b = count(0)

# Prints 0 1 2 3
for i in b:
    print(i)
    if i >= 3:
        break

# Prints 4, does not use a fresh count(0)
for i in b:
    print(i)
    if i >= 3:
        break
```

Is there a way to reuse `itertools.count` or otherwise get a reusuable/restarting infinite iterable?

Comment: Yes, please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49447520/5378816

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental problem is that `range` is an `Iterable` and `count` is an `Iterator`. `Iterator`s are objects that have a `__next__` method and can be stepped through only once, while `Iterable`s have a `__iter__` method, which can be called multiple times to return a fresh `Iterator` each time.

One solution is to simply create your own `Iterable` version of `count` which simply returns `itertools.count` whenever its `__iter__` method is called.

```
from itertools import count

class Count:
    def __init__(self, start=0):
        self.start = start

    def __iter__(self):
        return count(self.start)
```